# arduino wifi with cylon.js or johnny5.js

Tags: arduino, wifi, johnny-five, cylon.js

Do you know if is possibile to implement a wifi connection through Arduino one wifi modules using one of these javascript firmata (Cylon or Johnny5)?

Reading the guidelines of these frameworks I didn't find any information about this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out as well. It seems in all my googling the only demos of using johnny-five involve directly hooking the arduino into the host computer running nodejs and communicating over the serial ports. Anyone know of existing libraries out there where the ardunio can talk to the server running nodejs over wifi?

Comment: Maybe the only way to implement this feature is the arduino yun, but through python or php. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but here is a write-up for using [Johnny-Five with the ESP8266](https://gist.github.com/ajfisher/5fe60fe7d8c49b3223f0).

You can also use Johnny-Five with wireless devices like the Particle Photon/Core, Raspberry Pi, Galileo, Edison, Electric Imp, Tessel2 etc